# How do I send input() to a file that can be accessed and changed by user?

Tags: python, database, file, input

What I have now: (problem at bottom of page)

```
def end_task():
    print("\nError: Invalid input/User-Forced Shutdown has occurred.")
    print("Program shutdown.")
    exit()


def get_user_answers():
    answer = input("\n{0} Player List\n{1} Server List\n{2} Ally List\n{3} Enemy List\n{4} DNG Servers\n\n").lower()
    if answer.lower() == "zero":
        print(zero)
        repeat = input("\nWould you like to access another file? (yes\\no): ").lower()
        if repeat.lower() == 'yes':
            get_user_answers()
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")

    if answer.lower() == "one":
        print(one)
        repeat = input("\nWould you like to access another file? (yes\\no): ").lower()
        if repeat.lower() == 'yes':
            get_user_answers()
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")

    if answer.lower() == "two":
        print(two)
        repeat = input("\nWould you like to access another file? (yes\\no): ").lower()
        if repeat.lower() == 'yes':
            get_user_answers()
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")

    if answer.lower() == "three":
        print(three)
        repeat = input("\nWould you like to access another file? (yes\\no): ").lower()
        if repeat.lower() == 'yes':
            get_user_answers()
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")

    if answer.lower() == "four":
        print(four)
        repeat = input("\nWould you like to access another file? (yes\\no): ").lower()
        if repeat.lower() == 'yes':
            get_user_answers()
        else:
            print("\nGoodbye!")

    if answer.lower() != ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"]:
        end_task()


print("Hello! Welcome to the ---- Database! Made by \"discordname\"!")
print("Please try to answer all questions in lowercase.")
ans = input("What is the passcode: ").lower()

if ans.lower() == "----":
    zero = ["player1", "player2"]
    one = ["Server 1", "Server 2"]
    two = ["Ally 1", "Ally 2"]
    three = ["Enemy 1", "Enemy 2"]
    four = ["Server A", "Server B"]
    print("\nWelcome. Please specify what you would like to access (Answer in word form of #): ")
    get_user_answers()
else:
    end_task()
```

Trying to make a fun little database.  I want the user to be able to put in input like data = input("What would you like the new password to be?"). and then have that data stored for the next time I open the program. I was told by a person on discord I need to save the input to a file, but as a noob I have zero clues how to do that.

Also if I did send this input to a file, would I need to have my PC always running for someone to access the file or would the file be inside the actual program itself. Remember I'm a noobie so I'm trying to learn a bit and not just have working code thrown at me without learning it first.

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a discussion forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [ask]. Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Specifically, Stack Overflow is not meant to replace existing documentation, tutorials, and training programs. The Python tutorial, docs, and HOWTOs are excellent; I would advise reading thoroughly through them *first*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't exactly get input to a file but you can get the input from the user and insert it into a file. You open a file as `open("filename.txt,"r")` to  read or `"w"` to write or `"r+"` for both.

```
print("Hello! Welcome to the ---- Database! Made by \"discordname\"!")
print("Please try to answer all questions in lowercase.")
file1=open("path\to\password.txt","r")
xy=file1.read().strip("\n")
if xy!="":
    ans = input("What is the passcode: ").lower()

    if ans.lower() == xy:
        x=input("Do you want to change your password (yes/no): ").lower()
        if x=="no":
            zero = ["player1", "player2"]
            one = ["Server 1", "Server 2"]
            two = ["Ally 1", "Ally 2"]
            three = ["Enemy 1", "Enemy 2"]
            four = ["Server A", "Server B"]
            print("\nWelcome. Please specify what you would like to access (Answer in word form of #): ")
            get_user_answers()
        elif x=="yes":
            data=input("Enter your new password: ")
            file=open("path\to\password.txt","w")
            file.write(data)
            get_user_answers()

    else:
        end_task()
else:
    data=input("Enter your new password: ")
    file=open("path\to\password.txt","w")
    file.write(data)
    get_user_answers()
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. So the file is made by the program or do I have to have a file on my computer and have it refer to that?

Comment: No, you have to make it. If you want you can set mode as ```a+``` every where